# do something from AppIntent in an iOS Widget?

Tags: ios, swiftui, widget

i have a widget with a button that does an app intent, this is my code so far for the Intent

```
import Foundation
import AppIntents

struct DoNothing: AppIntent {
    static let title: LocalizedStringResource = "[デモアプリ]アプリを開く"
    static var openAppWhenRun: Bool = true
    
    @MainActor
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
                
      return .result()
    }

    
    static var parameterSummary: some ParameterSummary {
        
        Summary("Open App")
    }

}
```

What i want to achieve is to call a functiion in the view class that contains the button, is this possible and if yes how can i do it,  i tried various ways, but neither the variables nir the functions are accessible from the appIntents Perform function